# Is this a sign of arcing / fire / Bad Stuff?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Opened up a wall to plan some changes to electrical outlet locations, and found what looks to be charring on one of the cables.

It was stuck to the paper facing of the insulation. House is 20 years old, but I have no idea how long this has been like this. I haven't cut through the cable to see if individual wires are charred or otherwise damaged.

Is this evidence of charring / arcing / fire / other bad electrical stuff? This is a townhouse in northern Virginia.

**EDIT, more info:** No issues with the outlet previously. Usually had a laser printer and shredder plugged in. Back off the drywall that was over this cable looks normal, no nail holes.

[image: overview]

Comment: It sure doesn't look good! Maybe some arcing. More info would help. Have you had any electrical issues with the outlets in question? It looks like the the type of problem caused by a nail coming through the wall and hitting a cable. Some of the pros here can help you.

Comment: @HoneyDo added some info to the question

Comment: Clean the cable off with some mineral spirits and examine it further. It could just be some roofing tar that was stuck to the insulation and transferred to the cable.

Comment: You need to shutdown the power and inspect the cable for damage. @JACK has a point.

Comment: Agreed. that looks like the mogie "wicked" through the paper using capillary action. I'm unaware of any cable failure modes that would cause this.  Still, time for a basic health check on the cable, namely that the correct value breaker is attached to it, and it's a reliable type (if Challenger type "C" change to Eaton Type C/BR, if Zinsco or FPE sunset that panel as soon as feasible).

Comment: If that is heat damage the cable would have gotten hot enough to show some discoloration.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica mogie? Breaker is 15A, appropriate for the #14 wires. Breakers and panel are all Thomas & Betts